# getting JQuery .height() after appending to another div returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a div that is scrollable only when it's above a certain height after appending text to it.  I check the height using jquery and it returns zero every time.  Any suggestions?

```
HelpOverlay.prototype.buildContent = function(helpMappings){
this.content = $('<div class="content"></div>');
var table = $('<table></table>');
table.append($('<tr><td class="key"><h3>Key</h3></td><td class="command"><h3>Command</h3></td></tr>'));
this.content.append(table);
for (var whichCategory = 0; whichCategory < helpMappings.categories.length; whichCategory++) {
    var category = helpMappings.categories[whichCategory];
    var categoryDiv = $('<div class="category">' + category.category + '</div>');
    this.content.append(categoryDiv);
    var categoryTable = $('<table></table>');
    for (var whichMapping = 0; whichMapping < category.mappings.length; whichMapping++) {
        var mappings = category.mappings[whichMapping];
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        var keyCell = $('<td class="key">' + mappings.key + '</td>');
        var commandCell = $('<td class="command">' + mappings.command + '</td>');
        row.append(keyCell);
        row.append(commandCell);
        categoryTable.append(row);

    }
    this.content.append(categoryTable);
}

this.helpOverlay.append(this.content);
console.log(this.content.height());
}
```

console.log(this.content.height()) is returning zero.

Comment: It's working for me. Can you post a jsfiddle of it not working? (http://jsfiddle.net/2awqM/1/)

Comment: Your CSS could come in handy.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to this line:

```
this.helpOverlay.append(this.content);
```

Is `this.helpOverlay` already part of the DOM? Any element that is not inserted into the DOM will return 0 for height and width until it is inserted.

**Edit:**

```
this.content.css( 'display', 'none' ).appendTo( 'body' );
var dims = { 'height': this.content.height( ),
             'width':  this.content.width( ) };
this.content.detach( );
```

Comment: No it's not part of the DOM yet.  That's my problem.  I was wondering if there is anyway getting the height before adding it to the dom?

Comment: No, but what you could do, is set css `display: none`, add it to `$('body')`, get the height, then call `.detach( )` to again remove it from the DOM (you may not need to do the last part if you're just gonna re-insert it somewhere else since `.append()`ing it to another element just moves it). Don't forget to re-show the element when you're ready, though, with `display: block` (or whatever display mode you're using).

`this.content.css( 'display', 'none' ).appendTo( 'body' );`
`var dims = { 'height': this.content.height( ), width':this.content.width( ) };`
`this.content.detach( );`

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you don't need to wrap element creation in $() if you're passing it to another jQuery method. This is your code from above...

```
table.append($('<tr><td class="key"><h3>Key</h3></td><td class="command"><h3>Command</h3></td></tr>'));
```

But you could write it (and it would be more efficient execution) this way and it would still work exactly the same, except with 1 less call to $()...

```
table.append('<tr><td class="key"><h3>Key</h3></td><td class="command"><h3>Command</h3></td></tr>);
```